# Tmux: how to restore layout after changing it with select-layout or next-layout?

Tags: terminal, tmux

After starting a new tmux session I usually open multiple panes in the default window, and then resize them manually using the resize-pane commands (through shortcuts of course).

After doing some work, I arrive at a point, or have a certain kind of output, that I want to quickly view side-by-side vertically or horizontally. So I use the select-layout or the next-layout commands.

However once I'm done with these views, I want to go back to the layout that I set up originally. Is there any command/procedure that can let me do that?

Not only do I seem to not be able to restore to my original layout, I can't seem to do that with manual resizing either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can capture the current window layout using `display-message`

```
layout=$( tmux display-message -p "#{window_layout}" )
```

Note that this works in tmux version 1.7 or later. If you are using an older version, you could try extracting the layout string from the `list-windows` command. One way to do it is as follows:

```
layout=$( tmux list-windows | sed -e 's/^.*\[layout \(\S*\)].*$/\1/' )
```

and now you can use that variable, to restore your layout at a later time, with `select-layout`:

```
tmux select-layout "$layout"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't quite work but helped me with further exploration and I figured out what worked for me. I had to replace the first line with this:

    layout=$(tmux list-windows | sed -e 's/^.*\[layout \(\S*\)].*$/\1/')

And then I could use the second command to restore the layout.

Do you mind expanding on how the display-message method could work? In my case, the display-message just prints a string "window_layout}"

(my tmux is version 1.6, on ubuntu 12.04, FWIW)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought I was one of the few people still using 1.6 :) `display-messages` didn't gain the ability to process `#{...}`-style variables until a later version. `#{window_layout}` would give you the layout string for the current window, instead of having to parse the same string out of the output of `list-windows`.

Comment: thanks. I've edited the answer to add the parsing option for older versions. Looks like I'm due for an upgrade.

Comment: I've restored your edit since it was rejected (why?) before I had a chance to vote to accept it.

Comment: Thanks again. I have no idea about the reasons behind rejection. I wasn't notified either.

Answer (score 44):

Tmux has gained this functionality now as of v2.1 (see [CHANGES](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/ca29dc9abc5c90da1a56d06ecb692b35a3766bc0/CHANGES#L37)):

`* 'select-layout' understands '-o' to undo the last layout change.`

Comment: Would be great if you comment your solution not just a copy-paste from the CHAGELOG